# Proper JSON formatting a C# String

Tags: c#, json, unicode

If you do this in MVC:

```
var jsonData = 
    new { myimage = 
        "<img alt=\"\" src=\"/Content/images/ShowFPots.png\" />" };

return Json(jsonData);
```

You get this as a value

```
"\u003cimg alt=\"\" src=\"/Content/images/ShowFPots.png\" /\u003e"
```

How do I get this as a value, or will the <> interpret correctly when I add them to the innerHtml??

```
"<img alt=\"\" src=\"/Content/images/ShowFPots.png\" />"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that is correct javascript, unicode encoding. It'll be fine inserting it into html/DOM

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Unicode

Comment: <img alt="" src="/Content/images/ShowFPots.png"> is what inserts.  The <> are correct but it is missing the / before the end tag (/>).  Odd.

Comment: That is most likely the browser/DOM manipulating the html, but you can see the / at the end of your string in your question